# how to display data using java constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class demo2 {
private static final String String = null;
static String st;
static String[] split;
static int C = 0;

public demo2() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/madhu/demo1.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            st = sc.nextLine();
            C++;
            //System.out.println(st =sc.nextLine());
            String[] split = st.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                // System.out.println(split[i]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(C);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    demo2 obj = new demo2();
    for(int i =0;i<2;i++) {
    System.out.println("Splitted values are :"+obj.st);
    }
}
```

i have given input in text file as :
5,6
7,8
But in output it is printing:
Splitted values are 7,8   for 2 times
How to get exact output:
Splitted values are 5,6
Splitted values are 7,8

Comment: You are printing out the same value twice in your loop in your main function. Can you explain why you expected different values?

Comment: `private static final String String = null;` - what ?

Answer (score 0):

How to read and print file in constructor example.

```
public class App {

    public App() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(absolute path src));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new App();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to want to print each of the lines they read from the file, not each of the fields in the last line, which is what your answer does.

Comment: I am getting compilation error as:The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Comment: confirm, check please, my example "C:/Users/func/Desktop/Unsafe/src/main/resources/input.txt"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242231/how-to-parse-a-text-file-in-matrix-format-for-further-calculation   @АнгелинаНиконова Can you please look into it ? i am unable to solve this. please help